# MPI python program using mpi4py.futures.MPICommExecutor() does not complete execution

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I'm trying to write a simple mpi-based parallel program in python using mpi4py that asynchronously distributes some number of jobs among some pool of worker processes and then collects the answers when they're all done. I have the following python program:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from mpi4py.futures import MPICommExecutor
import math

def primefact(n):
     facts = [1]
     if n < 1:
          return []
     while n % 2 == 0: 
          facts.append(2) 
          n = n / 2
     for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2): 
          while n % i== 0: 
               facts.append(i) 
               n = n / i 
     if n > 2: 
          facts.append(n)
     return facts

def test_primefact(nums):
     with MPICommExecutor(MPI.COMM_WORLD, root=0) as executor:
          if executor is None: 
               return
          jobs = [executor.submit(primefact,qq) for qq in nums]
          facts = [job.result() for job in jobs]
          for rslt in zip(nums,facts):
               print('{}: '.format(rslt[0]) + ', '.join([str(qq) for qq in rslt[1]]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     nums = [qq for qq in range(1,201)]
     test_primefact(nums)
```

When I run the program using the command `mpiexec -n 4 ./mpitest.py`, the program execution will hang for an indefinite period of time. If I send a terminate signal by pressing Ctrl-C, the program will then print all of the output (so it did at some point do the calculations; I don't know if it did them before or after I sent the terminate signal), but it won't give me the command prompt back. If I send the terminate signal again, I'll get the command prompt back, but the processes that mpiexec spawned will still be running in the background and I have to manually kill them. Am I missing a line somewhere that lets MPICommExecutor know that everything is done processing so it can exit? As far as I can tell, I'm not doing anything materially different from the examples [here](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mpi4py.futures.html) and [here](https://programtalk.com/vs2/python/8776/mpi4py/demo/futures/run_julia.py/).

- mpi4py 3.0.0
- python 3.6
- Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS, Version 2019 Update 1 Build 20181016

Comment: Works for me, results are printed immediately. Which version of which MPI library are you using? Which version of `mpi4py`? Which version of Python?

Comment: I added the version info to the post

Comment: There may be a problem with either the MPI library I'm using or with trying to do this in a conda environment, because the examples in the links in the post don't work right, either.

Comment: Maybe this is related to my problem? I know I get the same errors mentioned in [this thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/799716).  I applied the fix mentioned in that thread, and as long as the threads don't have to communicate with each other (e.g. just print the process rank and exit), it runs fine. As soon as I introduce a `MPI.COMM_WORLD.send()` or a `MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv()`, the program execution hangs.

Comment: Nevermind. I got a version that just uses the `send()` and `recv()` functions to work. I still can't get `MPICommExecutor` to work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the program is in a file called `prim.py`:

```
$ mpiexec -n 4 python3 -m mpi4py.futures prim.py
```

Seems to produce:

```
1: 1
2: 1, 2
3: 1, 3
4: 1, 2, 2
...
197: 1, 197
198: 1, 2, 3, 3, 11.0
199: 1, 199
200: 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5
```